# How to using SharePoint sdk grab data from pages library?

Tags: sharepoint, sdk

what is the best practice on how to programmatically get the pages data from multiple pages libraries (from different subsite)

please provide me some link on that, thank you.

Comment: What do you need to do with the pages after you get them? It may alter how you want to get them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [SPSiteDataQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx)

Depending on the type of the page you could filter via the content type (e.g. "WelcomePage") or for all page types via the file extension "aspx".